# Airflow Import Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

We have configured the Airflow and there are two airflow dags working fine. I have created a new dag and can see the same in the Airflow UI . But when I try to turn ON the Airflow Dag from UI it gives me the following error
"DAG <sample_dag> seems to be missing".

I tried to troubleshoot the issue using the following ways:

1. Firstly, I tried to run my pipeline py file to see if there are any issues with it :

```
     python sample_dag_pipeline.py
['/home/airflow/airflow-install/dags/ABC_Middleware', '/home/airflow/airflow-install/dags', '/home/airflow/airflow-install/sample_folder/bin/python', '/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/airflow/airflow-install/sample_folder/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/airflow/airflow-install/sample_folder/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

It seems to work fine.

2. Then I try to run : airflow list_dags
   It gives me the following **error**:

```
  (env) [airflow@Airflow-VM dags]$ airflow list_dags
[2021-02-02 08:41:34,503] {__init__.py:50} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2021-02-02 08:41:34,507] {dagbag.py:417} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/airflow-install/dags
['/home/airflow/airflow-install/sample_folder/bin', '/home/airflow/airflow-install/dags/AirflowMiddleware', '/home/airflow/airflow-install/sample_folder/bin/python', '/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/airflow/airflow-install/sample_folder/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/airflow/airflow-install/sample_folder/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/airflow/airflow-install/dags', '/home/airflow/airflow-install/config', '/home/airflow/airflow-install/plugins']
[2021-02-02 08:41:35,044] {dagbag.py:259} ERROR - Failed to import: /home/airflow/airflow-install/dags/sample_dag_pipeline.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/airflow/airflow-install/sample_folder/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 256, in process_file
   m = imp.load_source(mod_name, filepath)
 File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/imp.py", line 172, in load_source
   module = _load(spec)
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 File "/home/airflow/airflow-install/dags/sample_dag_pipeline.py", line 8, in <module>
   from abc.def.gef import sample_dag_jobs
ImportError: cannot import name 'sample_dag_jobs'


-------------------------------------------------------------------
DAGS
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC_V01
DEF_V01
```

---

Lemme show my **sample_dag_pipeline.py** file:

```
(env) [airflow@Airflow-VM dags]$ cat sample_dag_pipeline.py | head -20

import sys
import traceback
from importlib import reload

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/airflow/airflow-install/dags/ABC_Middleware")

from datetime import datetime
from abc.def.gef import sample_dag_jobs

dagutils = reload(cai_jobs_pipeline)

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

DAG_NAME = "ABC_DataPipeline_V1.0"
```

**Observation:**

So in the above sample_dag_pipeline.py file I am referring to the code present in other directory(ABC_Middleware) by first adding it in sys path and then importing the modules from it.
I did the same for my other two dags(ABC_V01, DEF_V01) for them it is working fine but for this one it is not.

when I run the py file it prints me the sys paths and i can see the path added in the sys.('/home/airflow/airflow-install/dags/ABC_Middleware')

But when I run : **airflow list_dags** in the sys paths I am not able to see the sys path of my directory ('/home/airflow/airflow-install/dags/ABC_Middleware')

I have tried many options but all seems to get stuck here only. Can anyone suggest what could have happened?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem due to the fact you are using `abc` as a package, which clashes with the [built-in stdlib module of the same name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html), and since that is imported by Airflow before your DAG file is loaded, Python is looking under the system path for further modules.

Try re-naming `abc` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

- I had a similar issue. The import was definitely valid and worked when I ran `python my_dag.py` and also worked in a python shell.
- A restart of the airflow server fixed the issue for me